# How can I dissolve nickel(II) oxide?

Tags: solubility, transition-metals

To insulate $\ce{Pt}$ wire heaters, I plated them with $\ce{Ni}$. After switching on the heater for the first time, green $\ce{NiO}$ is formed which is insulating and protects the $\ce{Pt}$ from shorting. After using the heaters for a week or so, the $\ce{Ni}$ slowly falls away and the $\ce{Pt}$ heater shorts and cuts.

What is the best method of stripping away the balance $\ce{NiO}$ from the used up $\ce{Pt}$ heater?

Comment: It took me 10 seconds to find the Wikipedia page for NiO. It's a basic oxide.

Comment: Wikipedia says, its solubility in H2O in water is negligible. While it also says it's soluble in KCN. But KCN's safe use a bit of concern.

Comment: Can $\ce{HCl(aq)}$ dissolve it?

Comment: @DMHO http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1020634014278

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @Mockingbird, nickel oxide is somewhat soluble in potassium cyanide which will dissolve the oxide to form nickel cyanide, $\ce{Ni(CN)2}$ and potassium tetracyanonickelate, $\ce{K2Ni(CN)4}$  **but potassium cyanide is very, very toxic.**

### **Do not use it until and unless you are a professional chemist.**